# How to match some loans to lendings with equal sum result?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three tables: loan, lending, and matching in postgre.

**Loan table**

```
Id|amount|status|is_matched
1|500|active|TRUE
2|500|active|false
3|500|active|false
4|1000|INACTIVE|false
5|1000|active|false
6|5000|active|false
```

### Lending table

```
Id|amount|status|is_matched
1|1000|active|false
2|1000|active|false
3|1000|active|false
4|2000|active|false
5|2000|active|false
```

I want to match loan and lending amounts with equal SUM result for data with status=active & is_matched=false. For example, amount of loan with id 2 & 3 will be matched to lending with id 1 because SUM(amount of loan w/ id 2 until loan w/ id 3) is equal to amount of lending w/ id 1. Then, the matching will be inserted in the matching table like below:

### Matching table

```
loan_id|lending_id
2|1
3|1
5|2
6|3
6|4
6|5
```

After its inserted, it won't be matched anymore (set is_matched to true)

It's been three days I don't have an idea to do the sql query, lack of experience, in my mind maybe using sum with condition, but I can't make the sql query for this case. 
Any idea How and What's the sql query to match then insert data like that?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL <> PostgreSQL. I have removed all these conflicting tags. Please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: The row with `Id` 5 in table `Loan` also matches row with `Id` 1 in table `Lending`, correct?

Comment: I'd say, this problem is [*np-complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). Have fun to solve that in SQL.

Comment: No, Abra. Everytime the data matched and inserted into matching table, it will not be matched anymore. Maybe set is_matched to true

Comment: I see input, but did not see expected output. Maybe I am to tired, but I cant understand what the OP asks of us.

Comment: Ярослав Машко the expected output is like Matching table